# Execute C++ binary without leading `./`

Tags: c++, shell, terminal, executable

Suppose I have a file called A.cpp.

I used argc and argv in main to make it a terminal application, that means I want the program to work like this:

```
terminal> program [options] [input]
```

Given I compile it like this:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -o program A.cpp
```

When I wrote

> program [options] [input]

in windows, it worked just fine, but in ubuntu I have to write

```
terminal> ./program [options] [input]
```

is there a way to execute it without this " ./ " ?

grep works in ubuntu just like that and without the " ./ ", and I wanted A.cpp to run just like grep.

Comment: Yes there is a way to remove the `./`. No I won't tell you how to do it since it can introduce very weird behavior and even security holes. This also have nothing to do with your program, or programming in general, and should really not have been posted here.

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming itself, and all with how `PATH` works in Windows and the *nix world. In *nix, executables are not looked for in `.`, unless `.` is explicitly listed in `PATH`. And it's not a good idea to add it there, for security reasons.

Comment: Add the directory where `program` is to the `$PATH` environment variable.

Comment: what you could do is to make an alias in the bashrc see [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/154640/how-to-add-an-alias-to-a-command-in-terminal)

Comment: Also, what does this have to do with the `grep` command? Why did you add that tag?

Comment: I tagged because of it's behavior, which is what I'm looking for

Comment: But it's also true of any other program on your system; so this is not a question about grep - having the tag is unhelpful to followers of the tag, so I've removed it and added a few others more related to the actual issue :)

Comment: I think far more important question is why the OP doesn't understand why the ./ is required and what it means.... to which the answer is [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4430/why-do-we-use-to-execute-a-file)

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your shell, and possibly its configuration, it may already work.

Assuming you have actually tried, and it does not, then you need to put your program in a directory that is on your `$PATH`.

```
$ echo $PATH
```

to see a colon (`:`) separated list of candidate directories, such as `/usr/local/bin`, to where you could `mv` it, or alternatively you could put it anywhere you like, and add that to `$PATH`:

```
$ mkdir -p ~/my-progs
$ mv prog ~/my-progs
$ echo 'export PATH="$HOME/my-progs:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

assuming you are using bash (check `echo $SHELL`).

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to add your directory of executable to the PATH variable of your shell (this may change between some shells).

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/dir
```

If you would like to make it permanent you may need to add this to

```
~/.profile (or ~/.bashrc depends on your shell)
```

However, personally I prefer creating a shell script to prepare the development environment and run it whenever I need instead of hardcoding these values somewhere in the filesystem. By this way, you can initialize some other variables which may be usefuful for further development plans.

Comment: I added "export PATH=$PATH: ../bin" to the makefile and still it didn't work without ./ (when make compiles, it sends the executable to folder ../bin)

Comment: that's a very bad idea - putting relative paths in your path.

Comment: @Daniel after you change the path (if you did it correct) use source command (man source) to refresh your environment or logout and login back.

Comment: when i try ~/.bashrc it gives me permission danied (maybe cos I'm at university's pc)

Comment: try `source ~/.bashrc` (did you add your directory to here or somewhere else?). You should be able to execute that if you can change this file, this is your home directory. Of course I do not know anything about you lab. configuration

Answer (score 0):

You can place your executable program in /usr/bin

By example if your program is named *myprog* you can move it in /usr/bin/myprog,
then you can execute it from anywhere by typing

```
$ myprog
```

To give it execution permission if needed :

```
$ sudo chmod +x myprog
```

Comment: user programs usually put into `/usr/local/bin` it is not a good idea to use `/usr/bin` for that